# Could not find the function "getSymbols" while using ShinyApps.io

Tags: r, shiny, quantmod

I just finished building a trading strategy in Rstudio, and I planed to deploy it on the ShinyApps.io. Here comes a problem.

The first thing is that there is always a warning message like this:

```
Warning messages:
1: In getFromNamespace("checkEncoding", "shiny")(file) :
  The file "F:\newFinal/server.R" is not encoded in UTF-8. Please convert its encoding to UTF-8 (e.g. use the menu `File -> Save with Encoding` in RStudio). See http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/unicode.html for more info. Falling back to the encoding "native.enc".
2: In getFromNamespace("checkEncoding", "shiny")(file) :
  The file "F:\newFinal/server.R" is not encoded in UTF-8. Please convert its encoding to UTF-8 (e.g. use the menu `File -> Save with Encoding` in RStudio). See http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/unicode.html for more info. Falling back to the encoding "native.enc".
```

Even I saved the file with encoding UTF-8, it still shows me that warning each time I deploy the application.

Another thing is that I can't source the other file in ShinyApps, like this:

```
source("helpers.R")
#source("loadfunction.R")
source("main2.R")
#source("main.R")
source("plotperiod.R")
```

The following logs shows that the system can not find the function "getSymbols".

```
2014-11-30T05:01:21.252572+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: rmarkdown version: 0.0.0
2014-11-30T05:01:21.251463+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: Shiny version: 0.10.2.1
2014-11-30T05:01:21.253004+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: knitr version: 0.0.0
2014-11-30T05:01:21.517405+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: 
2014-11-30T05:01:21.517408+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: Starting Shiny with process ID: '25'
2014-11-30T05:01:21.524432+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: 
2014-11-30T05:01:21.524434+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: Listening on http://0.0.0.0:35292
2014-11-30T05:01:22.543644+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "getSymbols"
2014-11-30T05:08:22.837418+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: R version: 3.1.1
2014-11-30T05:08:22.838692+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: rmarkdown version: 0.0.0
2014-11-30T05:08:22.837469+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: Shiny version: 0.10.2.1
2014-11-30T05:08:22.839117+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: knitr version: 0.0.0
2014-11-30T05:08:23.115849+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: 
2014-11-30T05:08:23.115852+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: Starting Shiny with process ID: '12'
2014-11-30T05:08:23.122818+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: 
2014-11-30T05:08:23.122821+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: Listening on http://0.0.0.0:56837
2014-11-30T05:08:31.778390+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: Shiny version: 0.10.2.1
2014-11-30T05:08:31.779947+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: knitr version: 0.0.0
2014-11-30T05:08:31.778335+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: R version: 3.1.1
2014-11-30T05:08:31.779528+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: rmarkdown version: 0.0.0
2014-11-30T05:08:32.080184+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: 
2014-11-30T05:08:32.080190+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: Starting Shiny with process ID: '25'
2014-11-30T05:08:32.087453+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: 
2014-11-30T05:08:32.087455+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: Listening on http://0.0.0.0:55221
2014-11-30T05:08:33.083355+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "getSymbols"
2014-11-30T05:11:27.282921+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: Shiny version: 0.10.2.1
2014-11-30T05:11:27.284559+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: knitr version: 0.0.0
2014-11-30T05:11:27.282870+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: R version: 3.1.1
2014-11-30T05:11:27.284140+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: rmarkdown version: 0.0.0
2014-11-30T05:11:27.554872+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: 
2014-11-30T05:11:27.554875+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: Starting Shiny with process ID: '12'
2014-11-30T05:11:27.561737+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: 
2014-11-30T05:11:27.561740+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: Listening on http://0.0.0.0:33719
2014-11-30T05:11:34.514578+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: Shiny version: 0.10.2.1
2014-11-30T05:11:34.516275+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: knitr version: 0.0.0
2014-11-30T05:11:34.514528+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: R version: 3.1.1
2014-11-30T05:11:34.515806+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: rmarkdown version: 0.0.0
2014-11-30T05:11:34.784230+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: 
2014-11-30T05:11:34.784232+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: Starting Shiny with process ID: '25'
2014-11-30T05:11:34.791157+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: 
2014-11-30T05:11:34.791160+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: Listening on http://0.0.0.0:47994
2014-11-30T05:11:36.003478+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "getSymbols"
2014-11-30T05:12:10.176603+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: R version: 3.1.1
2014-11-30T05:12:10.177833+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: rmarkdown version: 0.0.0
2014-11-30T05:12:10.176681+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: Shiny version: 0.10.2.1
2014-11-30T05:12:10.178237+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: knitr version: 0.0.0
2014-11-30T05:12:10.483932+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: 
2014-11-30T05:12:10.483938+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: Starting Shiny with process ID: '33'
2014-11-30T05:12:10.491297+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: 
2014-11-30T05:12:10.491300+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: Listening on http://0.0.0.0:35973
2014-11-30T05:12:11.486962+00:00 shinyapps[shuttle]: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "getSymbols"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is going to solve the problem but in order to source the files, you will need to add the `local` argument and set it to `TRUE` as follows:

```
source("helpers.R", local=TRUE)
source("main2.R", local=TRUE)
source("plotperiod.R", local=TRUE)
```

Comment: This didn't help my cause. I am still getting an error.

Comment: Are you having the same issue as the original post and still getting an error? if so, can you please copy the output of `shinyapps::showLogs()`?